# Multiple divs drag

Tags: jquery

How do I drag and drop multiple divs using jquery UI?  Is there any option to accept an array of divs?

Comment: What do you mean by array of divs? Is `$(arrayOfDivsVariable).draggable()` not working?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds perfect for your need:
https://github.com/someshwara/MultiDraggable

Usage: `$(".className").multiDraggable({ group: $(.className)});`

Drags the group of elements together. Group can also be an array specifying individual elements.

Like: `$("#drag1").multiDraggable({ group: [$("#drag1"),$("#drag2") ]});`

Answer (score 0):

$(".divclass").draggable();

Will make anything with the class, "divclass" draggable

Answer (score 0):

you make in every div a class for example:

```
<div id="1st" class="go">
<div id="2nd" class="go">
<div id="3rd" class="go">
```

then

```
$('.go').draggable();
```

Comment: i am able to drag only last element using this method

Comment: have you made the div like my mine?